# wp_mail() or mail() not working in Wordpress contact form

Tags: php, wordpress, email, phpmailer

I have a contact form in this website http://dil33pm.in/contact/
The send button is connected to the file contact-form.php which has this basic test code.

```
<?php
   $to = "dil33pm@gmail.com";
   // Email subject and body text
   $subject = 'wp_mail function test';
   $message = 'This is a test of the wp_mail function: wp_mail is   working';
   $headers = '';
   // Load WP components, no themes
   define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
   $parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
   require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );
   // send test message using wp_mail function
   try {
     $sent_message = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
   }catch (Exception $e) {
     error_log('oops: ' . $e->getMessage());
     echo 'error failed because '.$e->getMessage();
   }
   if($sent_message)
   {
    echo '      <div class="alert alert-confirm">
            <h6>'.__("Your message has been sent. Thank You.", 'sr_xone_theme').'</h6>
        </div>';
   }
   else
   {
   echo '       <div class="alert alert-error">
            <h6>'.__("Your message has not been sent", 'sr_xone_theme').'</h6>
        </div>';
   }
   ?>
```

But I am getting error - Your message has not been sent. I tried to use PHP's mail() function, still no good. PHP is not returning any error, I turned on the debugging of PHP to see if there is any.

What could be wrong? I read about setting up SMTP, but I am not sure what is the real problem. My website is hosted in www.axoservers.com

Thank you!

Comment: Given that your calling code looks ok, it's very likely there is an underlying network problem. Check that your DNS is working, that you can connect to your mail server (local or remote) etc.

Answer (score 0):

This issue varies from host to host. I recommend using this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/